# Sampling a cosine

Tags: signal-processing, sampling, sampling-theory

If you sample a cosine of fundamental period 0.1 milliseconds with a sampling rate of 10^5 samples per second, how much phase difference is there between two consecutive samples?

I can't solve this problem and can't seem to find it's answer anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is the question i'm trying to solve. there aren't more details provided.

Comment: This question is just checking your understanding of the basic concepts. What are you having trouble with? Do you understand that there will be 10 samples per fundamental period? Do you know what "phase difference between consecutive samples" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine needs 0.1 milliseconds $=10^{-4}$ seconds for a phase difference of $2\pi$, so $\Delta \phi/\Delta t=2\pi\times 10^4$ Hz. Sampling is at $10^5$ Hz or $10^{-5}$ seconds per sample, $\Delta t=10^{-5}$ s. So $\Delta \phi = (\Delta \phi/\Delta t) \times \Delta t=2\pi 10^4\times 10^{-5}=\pi/5$.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't understanding how to get to the phase change. I understand now.